# Enabling navBar option dropdown is not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, dropdown

I'm having one issue on my navBar, I just adding navBar with `Dropdown`

I'm using this [navBar](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#user-menu-dropdown) of TailWind, so, the issue is that the option `dropdown` not work.

[image]

when I click on `button` the option `dropdown` don't work, I up the code in:

[code](https://replit.com/@JhonEstrada3/Nextjs-TailwindCSS)

you can help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, you have copied this from [Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/). If you really spent a minute reading [the documentation](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) you would see:

> Flowbite is technically a plugin that can be included into any existing Tailwind CSS project. To get started, you first need to make sure that you have a working Tailwind CSS project installed and that you also have Node and NPM installed on your machine.

This means you should install that plugin and I don't see any plugins according to your `package.json`. So install it like below:

> ##### Require via NPM
>
> 1. Install the latest version of Flowbite using NPM:
>
> ```
> npm install flowbite
> ```
>
> 2. Include Flowbite as a plugin inside the `tailwind.config.js` file:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>
>     plugins: [
>         require('flowbite/plugin')
>     ]
>
> }
> ```
>
> Additionally to your own `content` data you should add `flowbite` to
> apply the classes from the interactive elements in the
> `tailwind.config.js` file:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>
>     content: [
>         "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
>     ]
>
> }
> ```
>
> 4. Require the JavaScript code that powers the interactive elements before the end of your `<body>` tag:
>
> ```html
> <script src="../path/to/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>
> ```